# ¿Como obtener los parámetros de la url con angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, sailsjs

Se tiene una página web donde se comparte información de algo en las redes sociales por una url con un folio. Por ejemplo: `http://localhost:3000/operador/social/2017-0169` y cuando alguien quiera acceder a esta ruta. ¿Como puedo obtener la ultima parte de la url que es el folio para consultar la informacion y mostrarla?

He intentado lo siguiente pero siempre es vacío:

```
 var app = angular.module('socialPcApp-user', [])
  app.controller('socialController', ['$rootScope','$location', '$scope', function ($rootScope, $location, $scope) {
                         $scope.serie = $location.path();
                         console.log($scope.serie.length+"---"+JSON.stringify($scope.serie))
}]);
```

La verdad soy nuevo en esto y no se si la estructura de la ruta esta bien he visto que algunos en una parte de la ruta le ponen un signo hashtag(#)

Comment: Si utilizas la extension ngRoute de Angular te facilita esa funcionalidad [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams]

Answer (score 1):

Si el folio siempre estara el final de la url, puedes separar la url por el slash y obtener el ultimo indice del resultado que seria el folio:

```js
var url = "http://localhost:3000/operador/social/2017-0169";
var urlParts = url.split('/');

var folio =urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

console.log(folio);
```

Tambien puedes lograrlo con una expresión regular:

```js
var url = "http://localhost:3000/operador/social/2017-0169"; 
var folio = url.match(/\d+\-\d+/g)[0];
console.log(folio);
```

Comment: He encontrado la solución usando un poco de tu ayuda...

Comment: Comprate la solución registrada para las demás personas. Y si mi respuesta sirvió puedes marcarla.

Comment: he publicado la solución mas abajo...

Comment: Mala mia, no me fije. Me alegra que hayas encontrado la solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que con el `$location` permite obtener la ruta actual completa y con el split() obtuve la ultima parte de la ruta.

```
       $scope.ruta = $location.absUrl();
       $scope.serieArray = $scope.ruta.split('/');
       $scope.serie = $scope.serieArray[$scope.serieArray.length-1];
```

Como lo estaba haciento al formular la pregunta, obtiene un arreglo de los parametros de la ruta despues del #.